# Javascript populate array with IF statement

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a way to populate an array with if condition inside?

example

```
cars = [
  {id:1,color:'red'},
  {id:2,color:'blue'},
  {id:3,color:'blue'}
]
```

I need to create a new array that will get the value of ID and a new field which is type.

```
if color = red, type = 1, else type = 0.
```

I tried this one but it will not work for javascript.

```
var newArray = [
   for(var car in cars){
       newId: car.id,
       if(car.color == 'red'){
          type: '1',
       else
          type: '0'
   }
]
```

the return value should be

```
newArray = [
       {newId:1,type:'1'},
       {newId:2,type:'0'},
       {newId:3,type:'0'}
]
```

Help please

Comment: wrong object you have specified : cars =[
   [id:1,color:red],
   [id:2,color:blue],
   [id:3,color:blue]
];

Comment: Your array / object syntax is incorrect. Each car entry should probably look like `{id:1,color:'red'}`

Comment: Should the new object `type` property be the number `1` or `0`, or the string `"1"` or `"0"`? Your question shows it both ways. *"dont mind the syntax this is just a representation"* - Why would you *not* use standard JS object literal syntax as shown in all of the answers?

Comment: I fixed the syntax to use object literals where appropriate. I hope that's ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control) your original array to a new one

```js
const cars = [{"id":1,"color":"red"},{"id":2,"color":"blue"},{"id":3,"color":"blue"}]

const newArray = cars.map(car => ({
  newId: car.id,
  type: car.color === 'red' ? '1' : '0'
}))

console.info(newArray)
```

---

If you need to support IE, this will work in v9+

```
var newArray = cars.map(function(car) {
  return {
    newId: car.id,
    type: car.color === 'red' ? '1' : '0'
  }
})
```

Versions of IE prior to 9 do not support `Array.prototype.map`. See this [pollyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill) if you need to support those.

Comment: Cool! this one is the best answer and working for me. I will follow this. Thank you so much.

Comment: hi phil, will be possible if you can write the if statement as string? As i need to apply this to a string problem. I just used a representation of a small sample to show my problem

Comment: @ReyNorbertBesmonte do you mean that the "1" and "0" values should be strings? If so, you were asked to clarify that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44689945/javascript-populate-array-with-if-statement/44689993?noredirect=1#comment76363517_44689945)

Comment: yup.. lets make it if red = "this is red", else "this is not red"

Comment: I got it working thank you so much... It seems it has a compatibility issue on IE. It said it has syntax error. I need to find a solution for this one.

Working Fine in Edge, Firefox, and Chrome.

Comment: @ReyNorbertBesmonte IE doesn't support [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). I'll add an ES5 example

Comment: thanks, its working now. you the real MVP and has been a big help. really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
var newArray = [];
for(var car in cars) {
    var obj = {newId: car.id};
    if(car.color === 'red') {
        obj['type'] = '1';
    } else {
        obj['type'] = '0';
    }
    newArray.push(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given array is wrong, If your array looks like this :

```
cars =[
  {id:1,color:"red"},
  {id:2,color:"blue"},
  {id:3,color:"blue"}
];
```

then you should do this :

```
var newArray = cars.map((car) => { let type; if(car.color === "blue") type = 1; else type = 0; return { id: car.id, color: car.color, type }})
```

Comment: This modifies the original values. Doesn't look like OP wants to do that

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead your code:

```
     var newArray = [];
      for(var car in cars){
         if(car.color == 'red'){
             newArray.push({newId: car.id,type: '1'});
           } else {
              newArray.push({newId: car.id,type: '0'});
           }
       }
```

Comment: sorry, 2nd should be type = 0

Answer (score 0):

That's what the Array Map function is for, You can create from another array.

However, your array is wrong  and it has been corrected in the code below:

```
cars =[
    {id:1,color:'red'},
    {id:2,color:'blue'},
    {id:3,color:'blue'}
]
newCarArray=cars.map(function(car){
    if(car.color =='red'){
         return {newId:car.id, type:1}
    }
     return {newId:car.id, type:0}
})
console.log (newCarArray)
```